# OneToMany and ManyToOne relation in Doctrine - strange mapping error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mapping

I've got two entities mapped like this:

```
namespace App\Entity\Email;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\BlameableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\SoftDeletableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TimestampableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Blameable\BlameableTrait;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\SoftDeletable\SoftDeletableTrait;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Timestampable\TimestampableTrait;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Email\EmailRepository")
 */
class Email implements SoftDeletableInterface, TimestampableInterface, BlameableInterface
{
    use SoftDeletableTrait;

    use TimestampableTrait;

    use BlameableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    ...

    /**
     * @var Collection|EmailAddress[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Email\EmailAddress", mappedBy="sentEmail", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private ?Collection $senders = null;

    /***
     * @var Collection|EmailAddress[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Email\EmailAddress", mappedBy="receivedEmail", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private ?Collection $recipients = null;
    
    ...
     
}
```

and

```
namespace App\Entity\Email;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\BlameableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\SoftDeletableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TimestampableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Blameable\BlameableTrait;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\SoftDeletable\SoftDeletableTrait;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Timestampable\TimestampableTrait;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class EmailAddress implements SoftDeletableInterface, TimestampableInterface, BlameableInterface
{
    use SoftDeletableTrait;

    use TimestampableTrait;

    use BlameableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Email\Email", inversedBy="senders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn()
     */
    private ?Email $sentEmail = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Email\Email", inversedBy="recipients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn()
     */
    private ?Email $receivedEmail = null;

    ...
    
}
```

From unknown reason to me I'm getting message from Doctrine:

`The association App\Entity\Email\EmailAddress#receivedEmail refers to the inverse side field App\Entity\Email\Email#recipients which does not exist.`

What is wrong with my mapping? I really don't see any error. I've asked my colegues to check my code and they also don't see any problem. Strange thing is that relation sentEmail->senders is mapped according to doctrine right and it's working.

I've also tried to change OneToMany mapping to ManyToMany like [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) but I've still got same error.

EDIT 1:

Date in database:
Table email

```
id | created_by_id | updated_by_id | deleted_by_id | deleted_at | created_at | updated_at | subject | content
1  | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          | NULL       | 1616156920 | 1616156920 | Test    | Test
```

Table email_address

```
id | created_by_id | updated_by_id | deleted_by_id | address        | deleted_at | created_at | updated_at | sent_email_id | received_email_id
1  | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          | test1@test.com | NULL       | 1616156920 | 1616156920 | NULL          | 1
2  | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          | test2@test.com | NULL       | 1616156920 | 1616156920 | 1             | NULL
```

Comment: When are you getting the error message?  I made a simple test case without the knp stuff and doctrine:schema:create works fine.  And needless to say, but I'll say it anyways, try clearing the cache.

Comment: I've tried to clear cache and etc. This error can be seen in Symfony debug toolbar and the association is not working well. After fetching entity Email instead of Collection class in variable `$recipients` there is `NULL` and items are not loaded (they exist in DB).

Comment: Just for kicks, double check that your received_email_id in your email_address table has the expected values.

Comment: I've edited question so it contains rows from database

Comment: Do you initialise the collection inside __construct like this $this->recipients = new ArrayCollection()?

Comment: Take off your shoes so you don't hurt yourself when you start kicking.  Look closely at the annotations for Email::recipients.  Notice the /*** ? Took me an embarrassing amount of time before I noticed it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question/answer probably follows under the heading of a 'typo' but I thought it might be interesting to discuss.

The problem is here:

```
/***
 * @var Collection|EmailAddress[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Email\EmailAddress", mappedBy="receivedEmail", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
private ?Collection $recipients = null;
```

The extra asterisk /*** in the annotation block opening caused the recipients property to be skipped by Doctrine.  But everything still seemed to be okay.  The database tables and indexes were all generated as expected.

I made a simple console command to insert an email entity and quickly noticed that the sender address was inserted but not the recipient address.  Triple checked the various methods but still no go.  Explicitly persisting the address worked but the cascade option should have taken care of that.  And of course retrieving the recipient address was not working even after an entity was inserted.

At some point I noticed the /*** and changed it to /** and everything worked as expected.   Using a console command to test helped quite a bit as opposed to refreshing a browser and hunting around in the debug bar.

On the plus side, if you ever need to temporarily remove an annotation then just adding an asterisk is basically the same as commenting it out.

Comment: Thank you. You have really sharp eyes :D